# Check if the index of several combo boxes is unique

Tags: c++, winapi

I have six combo boxes which all contain the same values. I want the user to be forced to choose a unique value for each one. Is there an efficient way of doing this, rather than comparing each pair individually? Also, is there a more efficient way of assigning them with the same value, rather than just individually?

Comment: Sounds like bad interface design! What you're essentially doing is asking the user to order a set of values.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it's not the best method, but I need the user to assign six random values to six stats, and I couldn't think of a better way. If you've got any suggestions, they would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this properly, you want the user to choose values from 6 combo boxes, and be forced to choose a different value from the previous boxes that the user selected.

In this case, you could add an array of bool values equal to the amount of values that could be chosen from your combo boxes and initialize them to false, and each time the user chooses a value, check what the value is, check the corresponding element in your array, and if it is true, error out. If it is false, flip it from false to true and continue.

You essentially are looking for a data structure that will hold a specific piece of information: whether a value has been chosen or not. This can be implemented using an array or vector of booleans, or integers, or what have you.

Edit: the array would have to be accessible by the functions used to grab input from the UI. In an MFC dialog application, this would be somewhere in YourProjectNameDlg.h.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I'm asking. Thanks